# Jquery - attach 2 objects to make a clickable link

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Sorry in advance as I know how basic this question is but I'm struggling to find the answer to this.

I'm trying to connect two objects together, some text & a url and send them to a class.

The code I have that's working just fine is only using one of the objects at the moment;

```
$('.myclass').text(obj.mytext);
```

I'm stuck on how to attach the second object (obj.myurl) to this so it output's the text as a clickable link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoule

```
$('.myclass').html('<a href="' + obj.myurl + '">' + obj.mytext + '</a>');
```

or

```
$('<a/>', { href : obj.myurl, text: obj.mytext }).appendTo('.myclass')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.myclass').text(obj.mytext).attr('href',obj.myurl);
```